# How to set data-attributes with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html

How can data-attributes be set using code behind?

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Value" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" />
```

**VB**

```
lbl.Text = "Text"
pnl.Attributes("data-attribute") = "200"
//Is this correct?
```

**DESIRED MARKUP**

```
<span id="lbl">Text</span>
<div id="pnl" data-attribute="200">Value</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pnl.Attributes("data-attribute") = "200"
```

Comment: I see you changed your question after the answer, yes, that is correct

Comment: @Obsidian what's the issue, does attribute not render into markup? Please clarify in the question

Comment: Yes attribute does not render, I need to do further investigation myself before I submit a new question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I got it working using `.Attributes.Add(key, value)`.

Answer (score 3):

**C#:**

```
pnl.Attributes["data-attribute"] = "200";
```

**VB:**

```
pnl.Attributes("data-attribute") = "200"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.